# Form a list from a list which is in different order

Tags: python, list

I have a list `lis1` containing data:

```
lis1 = ['a','b','c','d','e',.....]
```

I want to form a `list - lis2` from `lis1` which should be in this order:

```
[
(b,a),
(c,b),(c,a),
(d,c),(d,b),(d,a),
(e,d),(e,c),(e,b),(e,a),
.....
]
```

I tried this:

```
for i1,i in enumerate(reversed(lis1)):
    for j1,j in enumerate(reversed(lis1)):
        if i == j or j1 > i1 :
            pass
        else:
            lis1.append("(%s,%s)"%(j,i))
```

But I am not getting the output in proper order:
I am getting this:

```
['(f,e)', '(f,d)', '(e,d)', '(f,c)', '(e,c)', '(d,c)', '(f,b)', '(e,b)', '(d,b)', '(c,b)', '(f,a)', '(e,a)', '(d,a)', '(
c,a)', '(b,a)']
```

Comment: What's the problem?  You reverse this list, and you're done.

Comment: Another possibility is to use **itertools** to create the pairs, and then **sort** the pairs, if needed.  Don't worry about constructing the list in the desired order; this problem is too short to worry about saving a few milliseconds.

Comment: the problem is that you're iterating through a reversed list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
lis1 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
lis2 = []
for i in range(len(lis1)):
    for j in reversed(range(0,i)):
        lis2.append("(%s,%s)"%(lis1[i],lis1[j]))

print lis2

['(b,a)',
 '(c,b)',
 '(c,a)',
 '(d,c)',
 '(d,b)',
 '(d,a)',
 '(e,d)',
 '(e,c)',
 '(e,b)',
 '(e,a)']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1, len(lis1)):
    for j in range(i-1, -1, -1):
        lis2.append((lis1[i], lis1[j]))
```